# How can I Save Stanza Word Tokenization Data in Single CSV File?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, stanford-nlp

I am using the following code to read data from CSV file ([Test](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qlGvHUw-bKsrq9e1wd6PeT3inDrAkXR_/view?usp=sharing)) attached herewith. After performing tokenization the output is printed on the console. But, I am facing difficulty to save it in the CSV file under Two columns ["Title", "Article"]. The tokenization code is given as:
**

```
import pandas as pd
import stanza
# create the stanza pipeline
nlp = stanza.Pipeline(lang='ur', processors='tokenize', tokenize_no_ssplit=True)
# read the csv file as a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv ('Test.csv')
# read the data from each csv column into a variable and convert it into a list
saved_title_column = df.Title.tolist()  # you can also use df['column_name']
saved_article_column = df.Article.tolist()

# create Document objects for stanza from pandas lists 
doc1 = nlp(saved_title_column)
doc2 = nlp(saved_article_column)
# enumerate and tokenize each sentence in the Document (Titles)
for i, sentence in enumerate(doc1.sentences):
    print([token.text for token in sentence.tokens], sep=',')

print('\n')

# enumerate and tokenize each sentence in the Document (Articles)
for i, sentence in enumerate(doc2.sentences):
    print([token.text for token in sentence.tokens], sep=',')
```

**

Anybody, please suggest to me the code to save this data in the CSV File under the same columns as in the Test file.

Comment: Caveat to folks looking to reproduce this issue who are not familiar with the `stanza` package: the pip package is almost 1GB, and there's a dependency on a file which is another 411MB.

Answer (score 0):

In the code provided above, the question is focused on the two for loops at the end -- each is supposed to be a column in a CSV.

First, there is a dependency not documented in the provided code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import stanza
stanza.download("ur")
```

Once `stanza` works, and the Urdu file is available, the first few lines work correctly:

```
# create the stanza pipeline
nlp = stanza.Pipeline(lang='ur', processors='tokenize', tokenize_no_ssplit=True)
# read the csv file as a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv')
```

Rather than separating the dataframe into lists, the `nlp` function can be applied directly to each element of the dataframe:

```
df_nlp = df.applymap(nlp)
```

In that approach, the rest of the transformations could be applied as another function. Something like

```
def get_tokens(x):
    list_of_tokens = [token.text for token in x.tokens]
    return ','.join(list_of_tokens)

df_nlp.applymap(get_tokens)
```

However, since I don't know Urdu and am unfamiliar with `stanza`, I resorted to modifying the original code:

```
# read the data from each csv column into a variable and convert it into a list
saved_title_column = df.Title.tolist()  # you can also use df['column_name']
saved_article_column = df.Article.tolist()

# create Document objects for stanza from pandas lists 
doc1 = nlp(saved_title_column)
doc2 = nlp(saved_article_column)
# enumerate and tokenize each sentence in the Document (Titles)
list_of_titles = []
for i, sentence in enumerate(doc1.sentences):
    list_of_tokens = [token.text for token in sentence.tokens]
    list_of_titles.append(','.join(list_of_tokens))

# enumerate and tokenize each sentence in the Document (Articles)
list_of_articles = []
for i, sentence in enumerate(doc2.sentences):
    list_of_tokens = [token.text for token in sentence.tokens]
    list_of_articles.append(','.join(list_of_tokens))
    
with open("output.csv","w") as file_handle:
    file_handle.write("titles, articles\n")
    for index in range(len(list_of_titles)):
        file_handle.write('"'+list_of_titles[index]+'","'+list_of_articles[index]+'"\n')
```